# Correct view output Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view

That's my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Spieler;

class SpielerController extends Controller
{
    public function getSpieler(Request $request){
        $spielID = $request->get('spielID');
        $spielerOutput = Spieler::where('spielPlanID', '=', $spielID)->get();
        return view('spieler')->with('alleSpieler', $spielerOutput);
    }
}
```

here you can see my view which I will trigger

```
@extends('app')

@section('contentSpieler')
    <h1>Spieler</h1>
    @if(count($alleSpieler) > 0)
        @foreach($alleSpieler as $teamSpieler)
            {{ $teamSpieler->note }}
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endsection
```

And here is my main index/app page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dateneingabe</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Spiele und Spieler AJAX - Drop Down</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @yield('contentSpiel')
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @yield('contentSpieler')
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When my controller is going to trigger i get back this in my console

```
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Spiele und Spieler AJAX - Drop Down</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h1>Spieler</h1> 2.5 Blasdasd
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I want only that `{{ $teamSpieler->note }}` should appear in my index/app page in the part `@yield('contentSpieler')`. What is wrong with my code? The correct value of note 2.5 is in the html console output but at the moment I don't know why there is no output on my index/app page?

Comment: can you show the output that you are expecting as I am a little confused

Comment: Output is {{teamSpieler->Note}} i want only this in my view which is included in the Second div

Comment: Your loop output seems to be `2.5 Blasdasd` (possibly 2 results) not sure if this is what you expect or not

Comment: first of all don't extend app layout as it has way more content than you need so either create a new layout for this or write the <html> and <head> directly on this view ..

Answer (score 0):

if your master view file location is view->index->app.blade.php then
your view file should be like this

```
@extends('index.app')

@section('contentSpieler')
<h1>Spieler</h1>
    @if(count($alleSpieler) > 0)
        @foreach($alleSpieler as $teamSpieler)
            {{$teamSpieler->note}}
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endsection
```

here your master view file location should be correct to extend it in your view file